# Graph Theory Question (Bipartite graph/Cartesian)

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that G and H are bipartite if any only if G x H is bipartite.

Can anyone give me an idea of how to start this proof?

Comment: A Cartesian product is bipartite if and only if each of its factors is. For G a simple graph, G is bipartite if and only if every induced cycle of G has even length.

Comment: The notation is in some need of clarification. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_graphs) the cross product notation is more commonly used for the tensor product of graphs than for the Cartesian product of graphs. From the title it seems that you're denoting the Cartesian product with it?

Comment: If $G$ (resp. $H$) has bipartition $(A, B)$ (resp. $(C, D)$), make a guess as to what the bipartition of $G \times H$ is in terms of $A, B, C, D$ and try to prove it. Hint: look at their adjacency matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: I’m assuming that you mean the product written $G\square H$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs). If $G$ and $H$ are bipartite, let the two parts of $V(G)$ be $A$ and $B$, and let the two parts of $V(H)$ be $C$ and $D$. Then $V(G\square H)$ is the disjoint union of the four sets $A\times C$, $A\times D$, $B\times C$, and $B\times D$. Consider a vertex $\langle a,c\rangle\in A\times C$; it’s adjacent to $\langle x,y\rangle\in V(G\square H)$ iff either $a=x$ and $y$ is adjacent to $c$ in $H$, or $c=y$ and $x$ is adjacent to $a$ in $G$. In the first case $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times D$, and in the second case $\langle x,y\rangle\in B\times C$. If you continue this analysis, you should have no trouble splitting $V(G\square H)$ into two parts that witness bipartiteness of $G\square H$.

The other direction is perhaps a little less straightforward to approach. Assume that $G\square H$ is bipartite, and let $A$ and $B$ be the parts of $V(G\square H)$. Fix an $x_0\in V(G)$, and let $$A_H=\{y\in V(H):\langle x_0,y\rangle\in A\}$$ and $$B_H=\{y\in V(H):\langle x_0,y\rangle\in B\}\;.$$ Show that the sets $A_H$ and $B_H$ witness bipartiteness of $H$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $G$ and $H$ are bipartite. Each circuit in $G\Box H$ can be split into  edges coming either from $G$  or edges coming from $H$ (but not both). These edges form an even circuit in $G$ and an even circuit in $H$ (not necessarily simple). The number of edges of  the circuit in $G\Box H$ is the sum of the two circuits and therefore even.

The other direction is also straightorward. If $G\Box H$ is bipartite there are no odd circuits in $G\Box H$. Since both $G$ and $H$ are subgraphs of $G\Box H$ there are no odd circuits   in $G$ and there are no odd circuits in $H$. Hence they are bipartite.