# Bipartite graphs/ cartesian product

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that G and H are bipartite if any only if G x H is bipartite. (G x H denotes cartesian product)

I saw someone else asked the same question, but the reply is only a hint on how to solve it. I am still stuck, and wonder if someone could give the whole solution. Or at lest some more direction on hoe to prove the "difficult" way, i.e where you assume the cartesian product is bipartite and then show that G and H are bipartite too.

Comment: The other question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300789/graph-theory-question-bipartite-graph-cartesian/300810#300810). That was a pretty big hint: it told you exactly how to split the vertices of $H$, and the same idea can easily be adapted to split the vertices of $G$. Where do you get stuck in carrying out that procedure?

Comment: I guess I didnt understand what you meant by "Show that the sets AH and BH witness bipartiteness of H". Maybe I am just being stupid!

Comment: I’m suggesting that you show that $A_H$ and $B_H$ are disjoint sets of vertices of $H$ whose union is all of $V(H)$, that $H$ has no edges between vertices in $A_H$, and that $H$ has no edges between vertices of $B_H$. In other words, all edges of $H$ are between a vertex in $A_H$ and a vertex of $B_H$ $-$ which is exactly what you need to know in order to conclude that $H$ is bipartite.

Answer (score 2):

To see that the product of two bipartite graphs is bipartite you can check that the product doesn't have odd length cycles.
You can suppose, for the contrary, that it does and this odd length cycle induces in each of the factor graphs a cycle one of them has to have odd length  and that is a contradiction.